# Creating a widget to list pages with a custom attribute

Tags: apostrophe-cms

This is my first foray into creating a site with Apostrophe so please forgive me!

I have created a custom attribute on pages similar to the following:

```
module.exports = {
  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
    options.addFields = [
      {
        name: 'include_in_list', 
        label: 'Include In List',
        type: 'boolean'
      }
    ].concat(options.addFields || []);    
  }
};
```

The aim is to now create a widget that displays links to all of the pages with this flag set but I'm struggling to work out where to go next... how to list the pages with the flag set and then expose that list to my widget's template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The straightforward (and more manual) way would be to add a `joinByArray` field to your widget that targets Pages and then manually join your pages to your widget. This will let you sort the order of the joined pages with a UI but has to be updated by hand to add more pages to the widget.
   https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-join-by-array-code

---

2. A way more like your describing (but a bit more opaque) would be to override the widget's `load` method and manually go fetch your targeted pages on page load.

in `/lib/modules/special-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Special',
  construct: function (self, options) {
    const superLoad = self.load;
    self.load = function (req, widgets, callback) {
      return superLoad(req, widgets, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        // `widgets` is each widget of this type being loaded on a page
        return self.apos.modules['apostrophe-pages'].find(req, { mySpecialProp: true }, {slug: 1, type: 1, _id: 1, title: 1}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
          widgets.forEach(function (widget) {
            // attach docs to each widget, in your widget template this becomes data.widget._pages
            widget._pages = docs;
          });
          return callback(null);
        })        
      });
    };
  }
}
```

In your `lib/modules/special-widgets/views/widget.html` you can access this array of pages in `data.widget._pages`

Note the `{ mySpecialProp: true }` is the criteria object for your find, set this up to find your page property.

Read more about the `.find()` method at [Working with Cursors](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html)

Comment: Thank you - in the end I opted not to use a widget for this as I didn't want to have to manually add this to every page but the above code showed me exactly what I needed to do to query the data and find the pages I wanted.